# Concatenate StringVector with Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, concatenation, rcpp

I can not figure out how to concatenate 2 strings with Rcpp; and the documentation did not help me while I suspect there is an obvious answer.

http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/working-with-Rcpp-StringVector/

http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/strings_with_rcpp/

```
StringVector concatenate(StringVector a, StringVector b)
{
 StringVector c;
 c= ??;
 return c;
}
```

I would expect this output :

```
a=c("a","b"); b=c("c","d");
concatenate(a,b)
[1] "ac" "bd"
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A working solution is to use :

```
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterVector concatenate(std::string x, std::string y)
{
               return wrap(x + y);
}
```

Then :

```
Vconcatenate=Vectorize(concatenate)
Vconcatenate(letters[1:2],letters[3:4])
```

Or :

```
// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterVector concatenate(std::vector<std::string> x,std::vector<std::string> y)
{
  std::vector<std::string> res(x.size());
  for (int i=0; i < x.size(); i++)
  {
    res[i]=x[i]+y[i];
  }
  return wrap(res);
}
```

Comment: Why do you say not fully Rcpp?  Of course it is or how else do you get the glue and the `Rcpp::CharacterVector` type?   But you forgot the required `#include` and the `Rcpp::export` tag.

Comment: I was referring to the use of the Vectorize function

Comment: The glue will work with `std::vector<std::string>` too; you could then loop inside <shrugs>.

Comment: Ok I add this solution

Answer (score 8):

There are probably a few different ways to approach this, but here's one option with `std::transform`:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

struct Functor {
    std::string
    operator()(const std::string& lhs, const internal::string_proxy<STRSXP>& rhs) const
    {
        return lhs + rhs;
    }
};

// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterVector paste2(CharacterVector lhs, CharacterVector rhs)
{
    std::vector<std::string> res(lhs.begin(), lhs.end());
    std::transform(
        res.begin(), res.end(),
        rhs.begin(), res.begin(),
        Functor()
    );
    return wrap(res);
}

/*** R

lhs <- letters[1:2]; rhs <- letters[3:4]

paste(lhs, rhs, sep = "")
# [1] "ac" "bd"

paste2(lhs, rhs)
# [1] "ac" "bd"

*/
```

---

The reason for first copying the left hand expression into a `std::vector<std::string>` is that the `internal::string_proxy<>` class  [provides `operator+`](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/6f81b4684481dbd9bb554dd95e66725fc3b63a8c/inst/include/Rcpp/vector/string_proxy.h#L248-L250) with the signature

```cpp
std::string operator+(const std::string& x, const internal::string_proxy<STRSXP>& y)
```

rather than, e.g.

```cpp
operator+(const internal::string_proxy<STRSXP>& x, const internal::string_proxy<STRSXP>& y)
```

---

If your compiler supports C++11, this can be done slightly cleaner:

```cpp
// [[Rcpp::plugins(cpp11)]]
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterVector paste3(CharacterVector lhs, CharacterVector rhs)
{
    using proxy_t = internal::string_proxy<STRSXP>;

    std::vector<std::string> res(lhs.begin(), lhs.end());
    std::transform(res.begin(), res.end(), rhs.begin(), res.begin(),
        [&](const std::string& x, const proxy_t& y) {
            return x + y;
        }
    );

    return wrap(res);
}

/*** R

lhs <- letters[1:2]; rhs <- letters[3:4]

paste(lhs, rhs, sep = "")
# [1] "ac" "bd"

paste3(lhs, rhs)
# [1] "ac" "bd"

*/
```

Comment: For a better understanding, could you briefly comment on how `internal::string_proxy<STRSXP>&` is related to `String` and why it is not possible to use `String`?

Comment: @Dominik In short, they aren't really related; `string_proxy` is basically a light weight wrapper class (i.e., a [*proxy* class](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Temporary_Proxy)) returned when individual elements are [accessed in a `Vector`](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/vector/Vector.h#L324-L346). This approach makes it possible to dress what would otherwise be a `CHARSXP` or `const char*` (presumably) with added functionality (such as multiple constructors, operator overloads, etc.) without actually storing ("owning") a `SEXP` itself.

Comment: Since the `string_proxy` simply holds a reference to a particular element in a given `CharacterVector`, this enables modifications to pass *through* the proxy object and affect the parent vector (e.g. via `Vector::operator[]`). On the other hand, `String` is more of a fully featured string class. Whereas `string_proxy` holds only a `static std::string` buffer, an index, and a pointer to its parent `Vector`, a `String` contains [more data members](https://github.com/RcppCore/Rcpp/blob/master/inst/include/Rcpp/String.h#L442-L455), so it will require more memory than the equivalent proxy object.

Comment: Additionally, since a `String` "owns" its underlying data (the `SEXP data` member) rather than holding a reference to a `CHARSXP`, modifications to the `String` will affect only that object and nothing else. Note how the two objects behave differently [in this example](https://gist.github.com/nathan-russell/a8395e1ca8b9ea4a57b5dedb95b833d2).

Answer (score 3):

I'm leaving this answer up, but note the warning provided by @nrussell regarding the use of [`push_back()`](https://gist.github.com/nathan-russell/1c0e18d517d54d9c4197aeae2de58b08)!

---

I'm still getting to grips with `Rcpp` myself, so I've gone for a string builder in a loop

```
library(Rcpp)

cppFunction('StringVector concatenate(StringVector a, StringVector b)
{
  StringVector c;
  std::ostringstream x;
  std::ostringstream y;

 // concatenate inputs
  for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++)
    x << a[i];

  for (int i = 0; i < b.size(); i++)
    y << b[i];

  c.push_back(x.str());
  c.push_back(y.str());

  return c;

}')

a=c("a","b"); b=c("c","d");
concatenate(a,b)
# [1] "ab" "cd"
```

---

Comparing the performance of (i) repeated calls to `push_back` against (ii) a preallocate-and-fill strategy, we can see that the latter is preferable:

```cpp
#include <Rcpp.h>
using namespace Rcpp;

// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterVector pbpaste(CharacterVector lhs, CharacterVector rhs)
{
    R_xlen_t i = 0, sz = lhs.size();
    CharacterVector res;

    for (std::ostringstream oss; i < sz; i++, oss.str("")) {
        oss << lhs[i] << rhs[i];
        res.push_back(oss.str());
    }

    return res;
}

// [[Rcpp::export]]
CharacterVector sspaste(CharacterVector lhs, CharacterVector rhs)
{
    R_xlen_t i = 0, sz = lhs.size();
    CharacterVector res(sz);

    for (std::ostringstream oss; i < sz; i++, oss.str("")) {
        oss << lhs[i] << rhs[i];
        res[i] = oss.str();
    }

    return res;
}

/*** R

lhs <- as.character(1:5000); rhs <- as.character(5001:10000)

all.equal(pbpaste(lhs, rhs), sspaste(lhs, rhs))
# [1] TRUE

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    "push_back" = pbpaste(lhs, rhs),
    "preallocate" = sspaste(lhs, rhs),
    times = 200L
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#         expr        min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval cld
#    push_back 101.521579 105.334649 115.156544 107.275678 110.957420 256.722239   200   b
#  preallocate   1.364213   1.585818   1.789564   1.778153   1.934758   2.955352   200   a

*/
```

Comment: As you said you are new to Rcpp, be aware that it is best to avoid `push_back` on Rcpp `*Vector` types whenever possible. The `Vector` class does not use a memory allocator so this function is much less efficient than, e.g. the `std::vector` counterpart. This is negligible for a length-two object, of course, but the difference can be significant for even moderately large objects.

Comment: @nrussell Interesting - good to know. I've also just noticed my output is different to what the OP requested...

Comment: @nrussell - I'm going to delete this answer; but I think your comment should be inclued in your answer as a note/warning to others?

Comment: I think you should keep your answer; apart from the use of `push_back` there is nothing wrong with your solution. However, you may consider adding another version which preallocates the result vector `c` to size, and then populates it by making a single pass with the `stringstreams`, etc.

Comment: And just as a reference point for my first comment, consider how drastic the difference is for only a [10,000 element vector](https://gist.github.com/nathan-russell/1c0e18d517d54d9c4197aeae2de58b08).

Comment: @nrussell - yeah, point taken :) - I've added your gist to my answer to serve as a warning to others

Comment: I hope you don't mind, but I added a comparison to your question which highlights this, as it is more directly applicable than the contrived example in my gist.

Comment: @nrussell - yeah no problem; it was late so I was going to do something similar this morning. Thanks for the edit.