# Concatenate NumericMatrix with Rcpp

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I would like to collapse the rows of a transposed NumericMatrix using Rcpp. For instance:

```
library("data.table")   
library("Rcpp")

dt1 <- data.table(V1=c(1, 0, 2),
                  V2=c(1, 1, 0),
                  V3=c(1, 0, 1),
                  V4=c(0, 1, 2),
                  V5=c(1, 1, 1))

cppFunction('NumericMatrix transpose(DataFrame data) {  
             NumericMatrix genotypes = internal::convert_using_rfunction(data, "as.matrix");  
            NumericMatrix tgeno(data.ncol(), data.nrow());  
            int number_samples = data.ncol();    
            int number_snps = data.nrow();    
            for (int i = 0; i < number_snps; i++) {    
              for (int j = 0; j < number_samples; j++) {  
                tgeno(j,i) = genotypes(i,j);  
              }  
            }  
            return tgeno;  
            }')  

dt1  
transpose(dt1)
```

Original Matrix

```
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5    
1:  1  1  1  0  1    
2:  0  1  0  1  1    
3:  2  0  1  2  1
```

Transposed Matrix

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]    
[1,]    1    0    2    
[2,]    1    1    0    
[3,]    1    0    1    
[4,]    0    1    2    
[5,]    1    1    1
```

I would like to have the following matrix:

```
      [,1]    
[1,]  102    
[2,]  110    
[3,]  101    
[4,]  012    
[5,]  111
```

Could anyone suggest a way to do this?

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/43182003/5977215) may be of use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe as a starting point, assuming that the numbers you concatenate consist only of a single digit:

```
//' @export
// [[Rcpp::export]]
std::vector<std::string> string_collapse(const Rcpp::DataFrame& data)
{
  R_xlen_t nrow = data.nrow();
  R_xlen_t ncol = data.ncol();
  std::vector<std::string> ret(ncol);
  for (R_xlen_t j = 0; j < ncol; ++j) {
    const auto& col = Rcpp::as<Rcpp::NumericVector>(data[j]);
    std::string ccstr;
    ccstr.reserve(nrow);
    for (const auto& chr: col) {
      ccstr += std::to_string(chr)[0];
    }
    ret[j] = ccstr;
  }
  return ret;
}
```

It gives

```
dat <- data.frame(V1=c(1, 0, 2),
              V2=c(1, 1, 0),
              V3=c(1, 0, 1),
              V4=c(0, 1, 2),
              V5=c(1, 1, 1))


string_collapse(dat)
[1] "102" "110" "101" "012" "111"
```

But a quick benchmark comparing it to a pure R-solution suggests that you should not expect miracles. Probably there is still room for optimization.

Comment: Thank you @Dominik, it was better then I expected, because now I don't need to transpose the matrix anymore.
I used to transpose the data.frame because it was easy to collapse the rows using data.table functions. But now, using the code your code I can collapse the columns and get the result I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have transposed the matrix you can collapse the rows as follows:

`matrix(apply(dt1, 1, paste0, collapse = ""), ncol = 1)`

Comment: Actually, I need to do it using Rcpp (C++) function, because even using the package tada.table, it takes too long, because most of the matrices I work have at least 700k rows and 5k columns. This is one of the code I have been useing to collapse the rows: 
    
`NewData <- OldData[, do.call(paste0, .SD)] `

Comment: I'm not sure you are going to see an improvement in speed here with your Rcpp function - since `data.table::transpose` is highly optimized for this sort of thing. Perhaps a better option might be to look at slicing the table up and running the operation over multiple cores.